# Making UnitOfWork testable

Tags: c#, design, unit-testing, separation-of-concerns, unit-of-work

I'm in the process of refactoring legacy code. Unfortunately it is a WebForms application with very tight coupling and smelly code. Currently access to database is inside models which looks something like this:

```
var fooModel = new FooModel();
fooModel.Select(sqlConnection); // Accesses db and populates model's data.
```

I would like to move this logic into Data Access Layer and in the process make it easy to test, so in the future I can migrate to MVC without much of a hassle. Currently the code does not use any ORM, so I have to stick to `SqlConnection`.

I figured out a way to abstract database access, but I don't know how to make it easy to test. I decided to make this hierarchy:

`Controller(currently codebehind) -> Services -> UnitOfWork -> Repositories -> SqlConnection to db`.

Basically `Controllers` can only see `Services` which use `UnitOfWork` to access `Repositories` to make use of transactions and retrieve data.

I created a sample to show you what I mean and what the current problem is. I used simple `List` instead of actually connecting to database, because it is just a sample to show what I'm looking for and I'm open to changing and rewriting this completely if someone has more knowledge of this kind of problems.

Example service:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    public int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var customerId = uof.CustomerRepository.Add(customer);
            var customerAddressId = uof.CustomerAddressRepository.Add(customer.Address);
            var customerAddress = uof.CustomerAddressRepository.Get(customerAddressId);
            customer.CustomerAddressId = customerAddressId;
            customer.Address = customerAddress;
            uof.CustomerRepository.Update(customer);
            uof.Commit();

            return customerId;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            uof.CustomerRepository.Update(customer);
            uof.Commit();
        }
    }

    public Customer GetCustomerById(int customerId)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            return uof.CustomerRepository.Get(customerId);
        }
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
 {
    public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository { get; }
    public ICustomerAddressRepository CustomerAddressRepository { get; }
    private SqlConnection _sqlConnection;
    private SqlTransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        _transaction = _sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

        CustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository(_sqlConnection);
        CustomerAddressRepository = new CustomerAddressRepository(_sqlConnection);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Example repository:

```
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _connection;
    private readonly List<Customer> _customers;

    public CustomerRepository(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _customers = new List<Customer>();
    }

    public int Add(Customer customer)
    {
        var id = _customers.Count + 1;
        customer.CustomerId = id;
        _customers.Add(customer);
        return id;
    }

    public void Update(Customer newCustomer)
    {
        var index = _customers.FindIndex(f => f.CustomerId == newCustomer.CustomerId);
        _customers.RemoveAt(index);
        _customers.Add(newCustomer);
    }

    public Customer Get(int id)
    {
        return _customers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CustomerId == id);
    }
}
```

How controllers(current codebehind) use this:

```
var customer = _customerService.GetCustomerById(1);
var specificCustomers = _customerService.GetCustomersByIds(new int[] {5, 63, 75});
```

With the current approach I cannot mock `ICustomerRepository` in my `UnitOfWork` class. Also I kind of mixed patterns and what I need together, so I'm not sure if this is the way to go here. What can I do to make repositories in `UnitOfWork` testable?

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem in testing.  You have class A that uses class B that uses class C.  So how do you *test* class B?

You must be able to mock class C and pass it to class B before you can test B.    In your case, we're talking about `UnitOfWork` depending on `ICustomerRepository`.  The trick is this:  if `UnitOfWork` is responsible for instantiating an instance of `ICustomerRepository`, you can never hope to mock `ICustomerRepository`.

You can fix this in two ways:

### Via constructor

An instance of `ICustomerRepository` is passed directly to `UnitOfWork`.  In other words, the relationship between `UnitOfWork` and `ICustomerRepository` changes from "`UnitOfWork` is owner of `ICustomerRepository`" to "`UnitOfWork` *uses* `ICustomerRepository`".  This is a far better place to be, and as a general rule of thumb, if you're using an interface, you should always ask yourself if the class instantiating the implementation *should* be doing so (more often than not that isn't the case).

Actual creation of `ICustomerRepository` is done outside `UnitOfWork` and passed in.  When you test, you pass your mock version of `ICustomerRepository` instead which doesn't connect to the database but acts as you'd expect an instance of `ICustomerRepository` to behave.

### Via property

Your second option is adding a setter to your `CustomerRepository` property.  `UnitOfWork` still instantiates `CustomerRepository` in the constructor, but you override with your own after the constructor.

This option is less pleasant because it remains the owner of `ICustomerRepository`, and yet adding a setter implies `UnitOfWork` just *uses* `ICustomerRepository`.  In addition to this, any business logic being performed in your constructor must be executed also on your mock `ICustomerRepository` instance before being passed, which is of course ugly.

However, it has the advantage that it behaves as it should unless overridden, meaning your code remains untouched except the new setter, and your test class simply adds a mock instance of `ICustomerRepository`.

Alternatively you could not instantiate `ICustomerRepository` in `UnitOfWork` and just leave the setter, but I don't generally like the idea of depending on the setting of properties in order for a class to function properly.

### Via an `IRepositoryFactory` interface

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory 
{
    ICustomerRepository GetCustomerRepository();
}

public class RepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public RepositoryFactory(SqlConnection connection) 
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public ICustomerRepository GetCustomerRepository() 
    {
        return new CustomerRepository(this.connection);
    }
}

public class MockRepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
    public MockRepositoryFactory() 
    {
    }

    public ICustomerRepository GetCustomerRepository() 
    {
        return new MockCustomerRepository();
    }
}
```

I don't know who instantiates `UnitOfWork` but at this point you would have your instance of `IRepository` passed to it and it would call `getCustomerRepository()` in order to obtain the `ICustomerRepository` to pass to `UnitOfWork`.

I assume at this point that `IRepositoryFactory` is dynamically loaded with your application.  Once your instance is created, you need not worry about exposing an instance of `SqlConnection` to the caller of the repository classes.  This also gives you the abstraction you require to be able to switch out the implementation of `IRepositoryFactory` necessary to perform your tests.

The whole point of these abstractions is to be able to change implementation easily.  As it stands now, changing implementation is not done easily and therefore *testing* said implementations is difficult being tightly coupled.

Comment: Let's say I use e.g. `DbContext` class that contains all repositories and I pass it to `UnitOfWork`. How would I pass `sqlConnection` to any of these classes? I would have to pass it via property which is not the best way of providing functionality.

Comment: @FCin So create a `IRepositoryFactory` interface which returns an instance of `ICustomerRepository`.  It is then implemented by `RepositoryFactory` normally which takes a `SqlConnection` parameter to the constructor and passes it along to all instances of `ICustomerRepository` created.  You then replace an instance of `RepositoryFactory` in your tests with a implementation that returns your mock version of `ICustomerRepository`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Where would I instantiate `RepositoryFactory`? Inside a service and pass it to every `UnitOfWork`? This would require me to expose `SqlConnection` to services which is now what I wanted to do. Could you write a small example of what you have in mind?

Comment: @FCin Answer is updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what you wrote it looks like `IRepositoryFactory` has to be passed in `UnitOfWork` constructor. `UnitOfWork` is used inside service classes and the instance of `RepositoryFactory` requires `SqlConnection` which means that services would have to provide `SqlConnection`. I would like to keep creation of `SqlConnection` inside `UnitOfWork` to keep separation of concerns. Please note I cannot use `Dependency Injection`, because it is a `WebForms` project.

Comment: @FCin Why do you say that you cannot use DI?  Seems like Autofac supports WebForms http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html

Comment: @ViktorSeifert I'm sorry, I phrased it badly. It is true that I can use `DI` for WebForms, but I would like to avoid it for now. Anyway, I think it should be possible to solve my problem without the use of `DI`. I will introduce it in the later stage of refactoring the application for sure.

Comment: @FCin Your problem is that your objects are hard to test because they are responsible of instantiating their dependencies. The solution is making somebody else responsible of that, a.k.a D.I. If you do not want to do it then your objects will still be hard to test.

Comment: If I pass `SqlConnection` from outside of `UnitOfWork` with e.g. `Di`, then after first use of `UnitOfWork` my connection will get disposed, so I would need to create instance of `RepositoryFactory` for every `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: Dependency injection is entirely configurable from that point of view.  You can make `RepositoryFactory` a singleton and therefore the same instance gets used everywhere.  Heck, you can pass the `SqlConnection` as a dependency to `RepositoryFactory` if you define how to create an instance (aka establish a connection).

Comment: Well, what I cannot figure out is how to pass the `SqlConnection`, because I create `UnitOfWork` myself. I cannot use `DI` for instances of `UnitOfWork`, because I create and dispose it only in scope of method(example i my question). If `UnitOfWork` would require instance of `RepositoryFactory`, even with `DI` I would need to have many instances of this class, not only one. I just cannot get a grasp on how to tie all of this together. I understand ways of providing instances of classes with `DI`, but with this example where `UnitOfWork` must be created manually I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Bottom line is that if you're testing `UnitOfWork`, the behavior of every class it uses must be passed.  If you don't want to pass `SqlConnection`, then pass something that can give you an instance of `ICustomerRepository`, or better still, pass `ICustomerRepository` directly (caller will worry about obtaining an instance of `ICustomerRepository`, not `UnitOfWork`.